# Can't animate multiple instances of an element with JavaScript. Only the first animation will be executed

Tags: javascript, animation

I have created an element called Particle. Single animation of this element also works. But as soon as I try to run multiple animations, only one animation gets performed. I think the problem is the `requestAnimationFrame (this.animate.bind(this))`-call, but I don't know how to change it to accept multiple animations at once. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Code:

```js
//gloabl vars
let particels = [];
let numberParticels = 120;
let canvas; 
let ctx;
let title;
let mesaureTitle;
let boundRadius;
let animations;

window.onload = function () {
    this.init();
    for(let i = 0; i < numberParticels; i++){
        particels[i].update();
        particels[i].draw();
        particels[i].animate(0);
    }
  
}

function init(){
    canvas = document.getElementById("c");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    title = document.getElementById("title");
    mesaureTitle = title.getBoundingClientRect();
    bound = {
        x: mesaureTitle.x,
        y: mesaureTitle.y,
        width: mesaureTitle.width,
        height: mesaureTitle.height,
    };
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    for(let i = 0; i < numberParticels; i++){
        let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerWidth);
        let y = Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerHeight);
        let size = Math.floor(Math.random() * 25) + 3;
        let weight = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) + 2;
        particels.push(new Particel(x, y, size, weight));
    }
}

class Particel {
    constructor (x,y,size, weight) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.size = size;
        this.directionX = 0.15332;
        this.resetWeight = weight;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.lastTime = 0;
        this.interval = 1000/60;
        this.timer = 0;
    }

    update(){
        this.weight += 0.02;
        this.y = this.y + this.weight;
        this.x += this.directionX;
        //check for collision with textField
        if (this.x < bound.x + bound.width
            && this.x + this.size > bound.x &&
            this.y < bound.y + bound.height &&
            this.y + this.size > bound.y) {
                this.y -= 3;
                this.weight *= -0.3;
        }
    }

    draw(){
        if(this.y > canvas.height){
            this.y = 0 - this.size;
            this.weight = this.resetWeight;
            //create random start point
            this.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width);
        }
          ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 180, 97)";
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.size, 0, Math.PI * 2);
          ctx.closePath();
          ctx.fill();
    }

    animate(timeStamp){
        const deltaTime = timeStamp - this.lastTime;
        this.lastTime = timeStamp;
        if(this.timer > this.interval){
            ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            this.update();
            this.draw();
            this.timer = 0;
        }else {
            this.timer += deltaTime;
        }
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)";
        requestAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The major problem is clearing the canvas inside the `animate` method of each particle. So if you draw multiple particles, each particle `update` call clears the canvas, overwriting previous particle data, which only leaves the last particle visible.

You could try removing the

```
ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

line from where it is and create a `createAnimationFrame` call back in `init` to clear the canvas before amimating particles:

```
function init() {
    // ....

   requestAnimationFrame( ()=> ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height));
   // existing for loop:
   for(let i = 0; i < numberParticels; i++){
   // ... .
}
```

However this creates (one plus the number of particles) requests for an animation frame. A better solution would be to remove requesting animation frames from the `Particel` class and create a *single* `requestAnimationFrame` callback which goes through the `particels` array and calls a class method to redraw each particle on the canvas with updated position.

---

Also the code generates an error in strict mode that `bound` has not been declared. I suggest declaring it globally rather than relying on sloppy mode JavaScript creating it as a `window` property for you.